# is there metric 'multi_logloss' for xgb crassifier?

Tags: xgboost, multiclass-classification

lgb has the log_loss metric

```
lgb = LGBMClassifier(class_weight='balanced', boosting_type='dart',
                         drop_rate=0.9, min_data_in_leaf=100, 
                         max_bin=255,
                         n_estimators=500,
                         bagging_fraction=0.01,
                         min_sum_hessian_in_leaf=1,
                         importance_type='gain',
                         learning_rate=0.1, 
                         max_depth=-1, 
                         objective='multiclass',
                          metric='multi_logloss',
                         num_leaves=31)
```

is there any  metric='multi_logloss', for xgboost classifier???

```
xgb = XGBClassifier()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41983544/which-is-the-loss-function-for-multi-class-classification-in-xgboost